# How to convert data contained in (managed) array<System::Byte^> to other managed types?

Tags: msdn

I'm reading in data as an array< System::Byte^ > in Visual C++ and want to assign it to managed types such as UInt16, UInt32, etc. How do I do this in Visual C++?

suppose I have a function parameter- array< System::Byte^ > receivedBytes, and I want to assign the first 2 bytes to a UInt16, and the next 4 bytes to a UInt32.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really (managed) C++ specific, but you might try using the various `To`* methods of the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzx26z14) class.  I've used them in completely managed C# (for example to read raw SHA1 values into 5 integers), and they work well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those. It is managed specific because in standard c++ I could do this easily with pointers

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant that my solution (not the question) wasn't managed C++ specific - in other words, BitConverter should work with C#, VB.Net, Managed C++, F#, etc.  Certainly in non-managed c++, it is trivial to do that with pointers. :)